# Add colgroup for each table column

Tags: php, jquery, html, css-tables

There are probably other similar posts, but here goes nothing.

I am currently reworking on an existing site and some of the changes required involves column and row highlighting, like here ([tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/) / [demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/RowColumnHighlighting/example-one.php)).

Since there are several web pages to go through, I would like to have some kind of shortcut to dynamically add `<colgroup></colgroup>` like in the example without having to go through each page and `table` by hand.

I've considered `php`'s `preg_replace` function, but I doubt that's the simplest way to go around it. In an optimal scenario, I would be able to verify if there is an existing `<colgroup></colgroup>` array for each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you could dynamically prepend the `<colgroup></colgroup>` to each table before your highlight script. Something like -

```
if($("table > colgroup").length == 0){ // If the table does not have <colgroup></colgroup>

    var colCount = 0;
    $('tr:nth-child(1) td').each(function () { // Get the count of table columns
        if ($(this).attr('colspan')) { // if there is a <td colspan>
            colCount += +$(this).attr('colspan');
        } else {
            colCount++;
        }
    });


    var colgroupList = '';
    for (i=0;i<colCount;i++){ // Add a <colgroup></colgroup> for each <td>
        colgroupList += '<colgroup></colgroup>';
    }


    $("table").prepend(colgroupList);

}

$("table").delegate('td','mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
 ...
```

jsFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/BGR22/1/

---

**Edit**
If you have multiple tables on a page, you need to add a selector to only get the parent table -

```
var $table = $(this).closest("table");
```

So now your `$("table").delegate()` would look like

```
$("table").delegate('td','mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
   var $table = $(this).closest("table");
   if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
     $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
     $table.children("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).addClass("hover");
   } else {
     $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
     $table.children("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).removeClass("hover");
    }
});
```

Updated jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/BGR22/3/
and with 3 tables - http://jsfiddle.net/BGR22/4/

Comment: This is very neat! However, after trying this on a page with multiple tables, the hovering works for each column. See http://jsfiddle.net/BGR22/2/

Comment: I have updated with a selector that would get only the current table, with an updated jsFiddle.